# Angular navigation when selecting the browser back button

Tags: navigation, angular6

How would you add a function such as this to several different components when navigating with angular router: "if the browser back button is selected, navigate back to this specified component, while not saving any of the users information that has been input".  I currently have this code but I want it to be updated to angular.

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).then(ref => {
if (window['ngRef']) {
window['ngRef'].destry(); }
window['ngRef'] = ref;
}).catch(err => console.error(err));
```